# Bug with my TensorFlow app, I can't seem to find it

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm very new to TensorFlow. I've absorbed what I can from the tutorials but I am stuck making my own thing. I learn best by doing, not reading, so I'm hoping to having something that works that I can tinker with to understand TensorFlow better.

I'm getting this error: "The shape of labels (received (32, 32)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (1, 32, 32))." I've fiddled with the code to no avail.

The program is supposed to read an image and spit out a "mask" image, which will later be used to cut out the background. a white pixel means "keep this" and a black pixel means "don't keep this".

pm.main is a file that contains a couple functions for loading the images, and one for creating the model. I tried to extract this stuff from the train.py ( for training ) and eval.py ( for running the thing ) to keep my code cleaner.

"pm.main":

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from PIL import Image as img
import numpy as np
import os

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    #return rgb
    gray = np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.3, 0.3, 0.3]).astype('int32')
    return gray

def load_images(dataDirectory):
    images = []
    for i in range(1, 2):
        filePrefix = f'{i:03}'
        fileName = '%s.png' % filePrefix
        maskFileName = '%sm.png' % filePrefix
        image = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(dataDirectory, fileName))
        maskImg = img.open(os.path.join(dataDirectory, maskFileName))
        maskImg.thumbnail((32, 32), img.ANTIALIAS)
        mask = np.array(maskImg)
        fixedMask = rgb2gray(mask)
        images.append([image, fixedMask])
    return images

class x():
    pass

def cnn_model_fn(input):
    input_layer = tf.reshape(input, [-1, 256, 256, 3])

    def addNewLayer(prevLayer):
        conv = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=prevLayer, filters=32, kernel_size=[3,3], padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
        pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
        return pool

    layer1 = addNewLayer(input_layer)
    layer2 = addNewLayer(layer1)
    layer3 = addNewLayer(layer2)
    # layer3 = 64 x 64 x 32

    #return layer3
    #flat = tf.reshape(layer3, [-1, 32 * 32 * 32])
    #dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=flat, units=64 * 64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    #dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=flat, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer3, units=1, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    result = x()
    result.logits = dense
    #result.logits = flat
    #flat = tf.reshape(layer3, [-1, 32, 32, 1])
    #result.logits = flat
    #print('layer3: %s' % layer3.shape)

    print('logits: %s' % result.logits.shape)
    return result
```

and "train.py":

```
import tensorflow as tf
from pm import main as pm
from PIL import Image as img
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np
import os

currentDirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
dataDirectory = os.path.join(currentDirectory, 'data')

images = pm.load_images(dataDirectory)

imagePlaceholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[256, 256, 3])
#maskPlaceholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[1, 256, 256, 1])
maskPlaceholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[32, 32, 1])

pair = images[0]
image = pair[0] # inputs
mask = pair[1] # labels

model = pm.cnn_model_fn(image)
logits = model.logits

print(mask.shape)
print(logits.shape)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
#saver.restore(sess, 'network.ckpt')


loss_op = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=mask, logits=logits)

result = sess.run(loss_op, feed_dict={ imagePlaceholder: image, maskPlaceholder: logits })
print(result)

resultData = result.reshape(64, 64).astype('uint8') * 255
print(resultData)

imageData = img.fromarray(resultData)
imageData.save('output.png')

saver.save(sess, 'network.ckpt')
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide an error stack trace, but here is my best guess.

Most probably the error is coming from the cross entropy loss: `tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`. If you look at the [spec](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy) you will see that this function expects `labels` to be 1 rank less than `logits` and all dimensions expect last must be the same (so that it knows which label corresponds to which set of logits).

In your case, labels seem to have shape of `(1, 32, 32)`. Assuming you just want to get rid of `1`, you can do `labels = tf.squeeze(labels)`